# how do post to a nested route in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i have a route at `/campaigns/{show}` which displays a page with an action button `'join campaign'`

```
i.e. /campaigns/{campaignId}
e.g. /campaigns/campaign-1
```

/apps/templates/campaigns/show.hbs:

```
...
 <button type="button" {{action "joinCampaign"}}>join campaign</button>
...
```

/apps/controllers/campaigns/show.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    joinCampaign: function() {
      // how to do a JSONAPI RESTful POST to /campaigns/{campaignId}/memberships ?
    }
  }
});
```

upon clicking the `'join campaign'` button i wish to do a JSONAPI Restful POST to a rest service listening for a POST to `/campaigns/{campaignId}/memberships`

i have created the corresponding nested route in ember

```
i.e. /campaigns/{campaignId}/memberships
e.g. /campaigns/campaign-1/memberships
```

Comment: Just create a membership record and override the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible options:

1. If you are using ember data, define a model with fields that match your API endpoint, and use [`this.store.createRecord(...)`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html) to create the model. By default, ember-data will try to "guess" the URL based on some [assumptions](https://www.emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html). Since your assumptions do not match, you will need to [customize the url in the adapter](https://www.emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#method_urlForCreateRecord).
2. If you are not using ember-data, you can manually construct the request using `Ember.$.ajax` (a convenient built-in [alias](https://www.emberjs.com/api/#method__) for [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)).

Note that defining the URL in your ember app is not sufficient: if you want two users on different computers to see each others' saved data, you will need a backend server with a RESTful API, separate from your ember app.